# Simple update is locked

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, innodb

We have a very simple InnoDB database. Just a bunch of tables with foreign keys, no triggers or anything like that.

We are writing Java application using Tomcat, Spring and Hibernate.

When we do very simple operation resulting in simple update in this table, the update is stuck (locked), and all other requests times out because of these locks. The exact error from MySQL is: `Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction`.

Looking in the MySQL, there are always 2 processes involved with this lock in each transaction: one is `Updating`, the other one is `Sleeping`. We found this a bit weird, maybe they are in deadlock? Why?

When we stop our app, and run the update manualy, it always works. So the table is probably ok.

Hibernate is configured for autocommit transactions, so there is no transaction handling in our app, all is handled by Hibernate.

We have tried:

- Updating Hibernate
- Updating MySQL (5.1 to 5.5)
- Changing MySQL configuration to [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMKB/MySQL+-+Lock+wait+timeout+exceeded+-+try+restarting+transaction).

`SHOW INNODB STAUS`:

```
=====================================
150113 16:01:57 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 42 seconds
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 439, signal count 426
Mutex spin waits 0, rounds 5145, OS waits 236
RW-shared spins 368, OS waits 184; RW-excl spins 18, OS waits 16
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 0 15578322
Purge done for trx's n:o < 0 15577923 undo n:o < 0 0
History list length 9
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 0 0, not started, process no 1599, OS thread id 140351479547648
MySQL thread id 1150, query id 15431 localhost 127.0.0.1 root
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
---TRANSACTION 0 15578321, not started, process no 1599, OS thread id 140351478748928
MySQL thread id 1149, query id 15343 localhost redmine_admin
---TRANSACTION 0 15578063, not started, process no 1599, OS thread id 140349944846080
MySQL thread id 879, query id 15207 localhost 127.0.0.1 root
---TRANSACTION 0 0, not started, process no 1599, OS thread id 140349945112320
MySQL thread id 878, query id 15207 localhost 127.0.0.1 root
---TRANSACTION 0 15578218, ACTIVE 318 sec, process no 1599, OS thread id 140351479281408 starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 1216, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 1121, query id 15351 localhost 127.0.0.1 root Updating
update anna.device set form_factor_id=null, device_level_id=1, connectivity_type_id=1, locale_id=211, os_id=21, app_version_id=1, family_account_id=68, device_role_id=3, device_type_id=14, platform_id=2, language_id=26, unit_system_id=1, timezone_id=7, screen_resolution_id=6, country_id=193, name='Martin\'s iPhone', active=1, running=0, time_created='2015-01-12 17:33:35', time_deactivated=null, device_uuid='4D420BD6-478F-47D0-A652-E746A912AE6F', ip4_wan=_binary'Q\'�', ip4_lan=_binary'\n\0�', ip6_wan=null, ip6_lan=null, has_camera=1, on_battery=null, battery_level=null, light_level=null, temp
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 0 15578219, sees < 0 15577724
------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 2 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 32770 n bits 224 index `PRIMARY` of table `anna`.`device` trx id 0 15578218 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 156 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 41; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 000001cb; asc     ;; 1: len 6; hex 000000edb09b; asc       ;; 2: len 7; hex 00000080191c23; asc       #;; 3: len 15; hex 4d617274696e2773206950686f6e65; asc Martin's iPhone;; 4: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;; 5: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;; 6: len 4; hex 54b3f75f; asc T  _;; 7: SQL NULL; 8: len 30; hex 34443432304244362d343738462d343744302d413635322d453734364139; asc 4D420BD6-478F-47D0-A652-E746A9;...(truncated); 9: len 4; hex 511f27b9; asc Q ' ;; 10: len 4; hex 0a0200b1; asc     ;; 11: SQL NULL; 12: SQL NULL; 13: len 4; hex 00000044; asc    D;; 14: len 1; hex 02; asc  ;; 15: len 2; hex 0001; asc   ;; 16: len 1; hex 01; asc  ;; 17: len 2; hex 0015; asc   ;; 18: SQL NULL; 19: len 2; hex 000e; asc   ;; 20: len 4; hex 00000003; asc     ;; 21: len 2; hex 001a; asc   ;; 22: len 1; hex 07; asc  ;; 23: len 2; hex 00c1; asc   ;; 24: len 2; hex 00d3; asc   ;; 25: len 1; hex 01; asc  ;; 26: len 2; hex 0006; asc   ;; 27: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;; 28: SQL NULL; 29: SQL NULL; 30: len 2; hex 0001; asc   ;; 31: SQL NULL; 32: SQL NULL; 33: SQL NULL; 34: SQL NULL; 35: SQL NULL; 36: SQL NULL; 37: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;; 38: len 4; hex 54b52644; asc T &D;; 39: len 4; hex 0000e306; asc     ;; 40: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;

------------------
---TRANSACTION 0 15578064, ACTIVE 566 sec, process no 1599, OS thread id 140351558203136
2 lock struct(s), heap size 368, 1 row lock(s), undo log entries 46
MySQL thread id 1091, query id 15391 localhost 127.0.0.1 root
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 0 15578065, sees < 0 15577724
---TRANSACTION 0 15577880, ACTIVE 1057 sec, process no 1599, OS thread id 140351558469376 starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 11 lock struct(s), heap size 3024, 7 row lock(s), undo log entries 6
MySQL thread id 927, query id 15347 localhost 127.0.0.1 root Updating
update anna.server set server_type_id=2, region_id=2, timezone_id=1, country_id=56, name='rdev', cpu_load=4, ip4=_binary'M]�', ip6=null, relay_countries='SK,CZ', cpu_score=862, tcp_port=0, rest_port=8443, udp_port=10002, config=null, tokens_active=0, memory=1822208, memory_free=464904, stack_trace_enabled=0, tokens_free=null, tokens_limit=500 where server_id=9
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 0 15577881, sees < 0 15577724
------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 7 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 29430 n bits 168 index `PRIMARY` of table `anna`.`server` trx id 0 15577880 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 101 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 23; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 2; hex 0009; asc   ;; 1: len 6; hex 000000edb317; asc       ;; 2: len 7; hex 00000080192bd3; asc      + ;; 3: len 1; hex 82; asc  ;; 4: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;; 5: len 4; hex 72646576; asc rdev;; 6: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;; 7: len 4; hex 4d5dc81f; asc M]  ;; 8: SQL NULL; 9: len 1; hex 82; asc  ;; 10: len 5; hex 534b2c435a; asc SK,CZ;; 11: len 4; hex 8000035e; asc    ^;; 12: len 8; hex 8000000000000000; asc         ;; 13: len 8; hex 80000000000020fb; asc         ;; 14: len 8; hex 8000000000002712; asc       ' ;; 15: SQL NULL; 16: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;; 17: len 8; hex 80000000001bce00; asc         ;; 18: len 8; hex 800000000002783e; asc       x>;; 19: len 2; hex 0038; asc  8;; 20: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;; 21: SQL NULL; 22: len 4; hex 800001f4; asc     ;;

------------------
---TRANSACTION 0 15577879, ACTIVE 1058 sec, process no 1599, OS thread id 140351480346368
40 lock struct(s), heap size 6752, 19 row lock(s), undo log entries 26
MySQL thread id 926, query id 15217 localhost 127.0.0.1 root
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 0 15577880, sees < 0 15577724
---TRANSACTION 0 15577750, ACTIVE 1374 sec, process no 1599, OS thread id 140351482476288 starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 15 lock struct(s), heap size 3024, 9 row lock(s), undo log entries 6
MySQL thread id 915, query id 15345 localhost 127.0.0.1 root Updating
update anna.server set server_type_id=2, region_id=2, timezone_id=1, country_id=56, name='rdev', cpu_load=2, ip4=_binary'M]�', ip6=null, relay_countries='SK,CZ', cpu_score=862, tcp_port=0, rest_port=8443, udp_port=10002, config=null, tokens_active=0, memory=1822208, memory_free=601266, stack_trace_enabled=0, tokens_free=null, tokens_limit=500 where server_id=9
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 0 15577751, sees < 0 15577415
------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 17 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 29430 n bits 168 index `PRIMARY` of table `anna`.`server` trx id 0 15577750 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 101 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 23; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 2; hex 0009; asc   ;; 1: len 6; hex 000000edb317; asc       ;; 2: len 7; hex 00000080192bd3; asc      + ;; 3: len 1; hex 82; asc  ;; 4: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;; 5: len 4; hex 72646576; asc rdev;; 6: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;; 7: len 4; hex 4d5dc81f; asc M]  ;; 8: SQL NULL; 9: len 1; hex 82; asc  ;; 10: len 5; hex 534b2c435a; asc SK,CZ;; 11: len 4; hex 8000035e; asc    ^;; 12: len 8; hex 8000000000000000; asc         ;; 13: len 8; hex 80000000000020fb; asc         ;; 14: len 8; hex 8000000000002712; asc       ' ;; 15: SQL NULL; 16: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;; 17: len 8; hex 80000000001bce00; asc         ;; 18: len 8; hex 800000000002783e; asc       x>;; 19: len 2; hex 0038; asc  8;; 20: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;; 21: SQL NULL; 22: len 4; hex 800001f4; asc     ;;

------------------
---TRANSACTION 0 15577748, ACTIVE 1383 sec, process no 1599, OS thread id 140351479015168 starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 35 lock struct(s), heap size 6752, 21 row lock(s), undo log entries 24
MySQL thread id 913, query id 15320 localhost 127.0.0.1 root Updating
update anna.server set server_type_id=2, region_id=2, timezone_id=1, country_id=56, name='rdev', cpu_load=2, ip4=_binary'M]�', ip6=null, relay_countries='SK,CZ', cpu_score=862, tcp_port=0, rest_port=8443, udp_port=10002, config=null, tokens_active=0, memory=1822208, memory_free=164184, stack_trace_enabled=0, tokens_free=null, tokens_limit=500 where server_id=9
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 0 15577749, sees < 0 15577415
------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 27 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 29430 n bits 168 index `PRIMARY` of table `anna`.`server` trx id 0 15577748 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 101 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 23; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 2; hex 0009; asc   ;; 1: len 6; hex 000000edb317; asc       ;; 2: len 7; hex 00000080192bd3; asc      + ;; 3: len 1; hex 82; asc  ;; 4: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;; 5: len 4; hex 72646576; asc rdev;; 6: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;; 7: len 4; hex 4d5dc81f; asc M]  ;; 8: SQL NULL; 9: len 1; hex 82; asc  ;; 10: len 5; hex 534b2c435a; asc SK,CZ;; 11: len 4; hex 8000035e; asc    ^;; 12: len 8; hex 8000000000000000; asc         ;; 13: len 8; hex 80000000000020fb; asc         ;; 14: len 8; hex 8000000000002712; asc       ' ;; 15: SQL NULL; 16: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;; 17: len 8; hex 80000000001bce00; asc         ;; 18: len 8; hex 800000000002783e; asc       x>;; 19: len 2; hex 0038; asc  8;; 20: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;; 21: SQL NULL; 22: len 4; hex 800001f4; asc     ;;

------------------
---TRANSACTION 0 15577746, ACTIVE 1437 sec, process no 1599, OS thread id 140351482210048
10 lock struct(s), heap size 3024, 13 row lock(s), undo log entries 16
MySQL thread id 911, query id 15219 localhost 127.0.0.1 root
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 0 15577747, sees < 0 15577415
---TRANSACTION 0 15577744, ACTIVE 1547 sec, process no 1599, OS thread id 140349945378560 starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 15 lock struct(s), heap size 6752, 5 row lock(s), undo log entries 2
MySQL thread id 909, query id 15226 localhost 127.0.0.1 root Updating
update anna.server set server_type_id=2, region_id=2, timezone_id=1, country_id=56, name='rdev', cpu_load=1, ip4=_binary'M]�', ip6=null, relay_countries='SK,CZ', cpu_score=862, tcp_port=0, rest_port=8443, udp_port=10002, config=null, tokens_active=0, memory=1822208, memory_free=481920, stack_trace_enabled=0, tokens_free=null, tokens_limit=500 where server_id=9
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 0 15577745, sees < 0 15577415
------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 37 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 29430 n bits 168 index `PRIMARY` of table `anna`.`server` trx id 0 15577744 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 101 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 23; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 2; hex 0009; asc   ;; 1: len 6; hex 000000edb317; asc       ;; 2: len 7; hex 00000080192bd3; asc      + ;; 3: len 1; hex 82; asc  ;; 4: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;; 5: len 4; hex 72646576; asc rdev;; 6: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;; 7: len 4; hex 4d5dc81f; asc M]  ;; 8: SQL NULL; 9: len 1; hex 82; asc  ;; 10: len 5; hex 534b2c435a; asc SK,CZ;; 11: len 4; hex 8000035e; asc    ^;; 12: len 8; hex 8000000000000000; asc         ;; 13: len 8; hex 80000000000020fb; asc         ;; 14: len 8; hex 8000000000002712; asc       ' ;; 15: SQL NULL; 16: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;; 17: len 8; hex 80000000001bce00; asc         ;; 18: len 8; hex 800000000002783e; asc       x>;; 19: len 2; hex 0038; asc  8;; 20: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;; 21: SQL NULL; 22: len 4; hex 800001f4; asc     ;;

------------------
---TRANSACTION 0 15577730, ACTIVE 1557 sec, process no 1599, OS thread id 140351483541248
10 lock struct(s), heap size 3024, 10 row lock(s), undo log entries 13
MySQL thread id 895, query id 15184 localhost 127.0.0.1 root
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 0 15577731, sees < 0 15577415
---TRANSACTION 0 15577729, ACTIVE 1567 sec, process no 1599, OS thread id 140351559001856 starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 11 lock struct(s), heap size 3024, 7 row lock(s), undo log entries 3
MySQL thread id 894, query id 15224 localhost 127.0.0.1 root Updating
update anna.server set server_type_id=2, region_id=2, timezone_id=1, country_id=56, name='rdev', cpu_load=1, ip4=_binary'M]�', ip6=null, relay_countries='SK,CZ', cpu_score=862, tcp_port=0, rest_port=8443, udp_port=10002, config=null, tokens_active=0, memory=1822208, memory_free=492131, stack_trace_enabled=0, tokens_free=null, tokens_limit=500 where server_id=9
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 0 15577730, sees < 0 15577415
------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 47 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 29430 n bits 168 index `PRIMARY` of table `anna`.`server` trx id 0 15577729 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 101 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 23; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 2; hex 0009; asc   ;; 1: len 6; hex 000000edb317; asc       ;; 2: len 7; hex 00000080192bd3; asc      + ;; 3: len 1; hex 82; asc  ;; 4: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;; 5: len 4; hex 72646576; asc rdev;; 6: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;; 7: len 4; hex 4d5dc81f; asc M]  ;; 8: SQL NULL; 9: len 1; hex 82; asc  ;; 10: len 5; hex 534b2c435a; asc SK,CZ;; 11: len 4; hex 8000035e; asc    ^;; 12: len 8; hex 8000000000000000; asc         ;; 13: len 8; hex 80000000000020fb; asc         ;; 14: len 8; hex 8000000000002712; asc       ' ;; 15: SQL NULL; 16: len 4; hex 80000000; asc     ;; 17: len 8; hex 80000000001bce00; asc         ;; 18: len 8; hex 800000000002783e; asc       x>;; 19: len 2; hex 0038; asc  8;; 20: len 1; hex 80; asc  ;; 21: SQL NULL; 22: len 4; hex 800001f4; asc     ;;

------------------
---TRANSACTION 0 15577727, ACTIVE 1617 sec, process no 1599, OS thread id 140349944579840
10 lock struct(s), heap size 3024, 4 row lock(s), undo log entries 2
MySQL thread id 892, query id 15221 localhost 127.0.0.1 root
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 0 15577728, sees < 0 15577415
---TRANSACTION 0 15577724, ACTIVE 1648 sec, process no 1599, OS thread id 140351483275008
14 lock struct(s), heap size 6752, 11 row lock(s), undo log entries 34
MySQL thread id 889, query id 15430 localhost 127.0.0.1 root
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 0 15577725, sees < 0 15577415
--------
FILE I/O
--------
I/O thread 0 state: waiting for i/o request (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: waiting for i/o request (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: waiting for i/o request (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: waiting for i/o request (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: 0, aio writes: 0,
 ibuf aio reads: 0, log i/o's: 0, sync i/o's: 0
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
786 OS file reads, 2712 OS file writes, 1137 OS fsyncs
0.07 reads/s, 16384 avg bytes/read, 0.05 writes/s, 0.05 fsyncs/s
-------------------------------------
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
-------------------------------------
Ibuf: size 1, free list len 9, seg size 11,
428 inserts, 428 merged recs, 69 merges
Hash table size 2212699, node heap has 9 buffer(s)
5.00 hash searches/s, 15.43 non-hash searches/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number 0 1679880718
Log flushed up to   0 1679878430
Last checkpoint at  0 1679871205
0 pending log writes, 0 pending chkp writes
758 log i/o's done, 0.05 log i/o's/second
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total memory allocated 1216262384; in additional pool allocated 1048576
Dictionary memory allocated 786512
Buffer pool size   65536
Free buffers       64458
Database pages     1069
Modified db pages  25
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages read 1062, created 7, written 2508
0.07 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.00 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
13 read views open inside InnoDB
Main thread process no. 1599, id 140349909063424, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 438, updated 282, deleted 0, read 335130
0.48 inserts/s, 0.50 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 337.68 reads/s
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================
```

The method for saving objects (resulting in those updates) is just the following code, the rest is *Hibernate magic*.

```java
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@Repository("dbHome")
public class DbHome {
    @Autowired(required=true)
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    // Other CRUD methods are here

    public void saveObject(final Object object) {
        final Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.saveOrUpdate(object);
    }
}
```

Hibernate configuration:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory name="">
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/anna?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">xxxxx</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">xxxxx</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.schema">anna</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
        <!-- Mappings -->
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Ehrm you don't want autocommit, this basically means you don't have transactions. Each sql statement is executed in its own transaction, if something fails you will be in trouble if there aer multiple statements.

Comment: If I understand the docs correctly, I can still use `@Transactional` annotation to put multiple statements in one transaction. And I can also disable autocommit in code, if I'll ever need to. But in 90 %, we don't. And, we also did this for debuging purposes.

Comment: Of course you can but relying on auto-commit isn't something I would do for a production system, just my 2ct. Eventually it will lead to problems you haven't foreseen, then it is better to be in control of your transactions. However if I recall correctly you should always use a transaction with hibernate else it doesn't know when to flush changes to the database, leaving them hanging. Can you show some code that is doing updates?

Comment: I added the code resulting in those updates...

Comment: Apparently you have tx setup as you are using `getCurrentSession`. If you wouldn't use transactions this would result in an exception. Can you post the hibernate configuration.

Comment: @M.Deinum Well, they are probably created because of autocommit. And I added Hibernate configuration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68867/discussion-between-pitel-and-m-deinum).

Comment: `<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>` there is your culprit. As you are managing your sessions yourself and don't want spring to manage your transactions you will have to manage everything yourself. Call `session.close()` and probably before that `session.flush()` . However as stated I would suggest setting up transactions correctly and then your code would work.

Comment: I don't think we are handling the session ourself. I think that's why `@Autowired` annotation near `sessionFactory` is for. When I just tried adding `session.flush()` and `session.close()` after `session.saveOrUpdate(object)` I get `org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!` in other CRUD methods, which also just use `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`.

Comment: `@Autowired` has nothing to do with that. You are doing manual session management due to the fact that you set the `current_session_context_class` to thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks to @M.Deinum, I've found a solution.

First, remove/comment the following line from Hibernate configuration.

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

Then, add the following line to your Spring context configuration. Don't forgot to add proper namespaces, more info/example [here](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/hibernate-transaction-annotation-config-code-example.html).

```
<tx:annotation-driven/>
```

Also make sure you have `transactionManager` bean nearby.

The last step is to add `@Transactional` annotation after (I read it's import to place it after) `@Repository` annotation.